# how to select a random value from range by condition VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Hello everyone.

I've got a range of products that I want to select 10 of them randomic every day by condition.

if the product was selected in the last 30 days, then the code will select another product that was'nt selected in the last 30 days.

I'm trying to think about the code for long time and I dont have nothing!

**Please help me!**

Comment: This is too vague to consider. Do provide examples of data, what you specifically trying to do, and some meaningful code you wrote towards that goal.

Answer (score 0):

i have tried at answer your question...i have wrote this code that works...
in this code i have used two sheets

**1** sheet "product" where are the products in column A

**2** sheet "productUsed" where there are all the product used with the date.

Keep me updated

**In this image(sheet product) we have the products** (I used 100 products for the test)

[image]

**in this image(sheet productUsed) we have the result**

[image]

the code of follow:

```
Sub test()

'i use this variable to get the difference between the dates(number of the days).
Dim d As String

Dim item As Boolean
Dim productChoosed As String
Dim numProduct, i, c, numChoosedProduct As Long
Dim wsProductUsed As Worksheet

Set wsProductUsed = Worksheets("productUsed")

'count the product's number into sheet product
numProduct = Cells(rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - 1

For i = 1 To 10
    item = False ' use this variable to understand if the item choosed random is present or no into list of the product used
    productChoosed = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(2, numProduct) 'choose product from 2 to max num product into productsheet
    With wsProductUsed
        'count the product's number coosed into sheet productUsed
        numChoosedProduct = .Cells(.rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        For c = 1 To numChoosedProduct
            If (Cells(productChoosed, 1) = .Cells(c, 1)) Then
                d = CDate(Date) - CDate(.Cells(c, 2))
                item = True

                If d < 30 Then
                    i = i - 1
                    c = numChoosedProduct ' exit for with c index
                Else
                    .Cells(c, 2) = Date
                    c = numChoosedProduct ' exit for with c index
                End If
            End If
        Next c
        'if new item never choosed i add it into list of items choosed
        If item = False Then
           .Cells(numChoosedProduct + 1, 1) = Cells(productChoosed, 1)
           .Cells(numChoosedProduct + 1, 2) = Date
        End If
    End With
Next i

'auto fit the columns
Sheets("productUsed").Columns.AutoFit


End Sub
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help.

I've found a solution thats work fine:

```
Sub Action_1()
Dim DATA_1, DATA_2 As Range
Set DATA_1 = Sheets("Data").Range("b4:b53")
Set DATA_2 = Sheets("Data").Range("b54:b253")

Sheets("count").Select
irow = 2
' loop for the catagory that need to count one a month
For irow = 2 To 5
' checking if the product was count this month and removing duplicate
    Do Until Cells(irow, 7) = 0 And Cells(irow, 8) = 0
        Cells(irow, 1).Value = Evaluate("=INDEX(DATA_1,RANDBETWEEN(1,rows(DATA_1)),1)")
    Loop
Next
irow = 6
' loop for the catagory that need to count one a qurter
For irow = 6 To 11
' checking if the product was count this qurter and removing duplicate
    Do Until Cells(irow, 7) = 0 And Cells(irow, 8) = 0
        Cells(irow, 1).Value = Evaluate("=INDEX(DATA_2,RANDBETWEEN(1,rows(DATA_2)),1)")
    Loop
Next
End Sub
```

This code requires a separate sheet to work with it:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGzln.jpg